# Access a shared folder of a different machine with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to access a shared folder of a different machine (Mapped to my
server) say E:\ (which is actually \myothermac\c$\somefolder") from C#.

If I use

```
string strFolder = "E:\myNewFolder";

if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(strFolder))
{ ... }
```

it always says the **directory doesn't exist**. I thought it might be
something to do with security and I enabled everyone to have full access
on the other machine. But it didnt help.

I know ASPNET user will not know the share created by any other user on
the machine, but how do you suggest me do it?

I even tried this:

```
string strFolder = "\\\\MyOtherMachine\\c$\\myNewFolder";
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(strFolder))
{ ... }
```

Comment: Does asp.net user has rights to the folder you are trying to access ?

Comment: Yes.The asp.net user has rights to the folder

Comment: did u try to access using the IP?

Comment: Yes.I am trying with IP address only

Answer (score 0):

You can DriveInfo class for this purpose a more detailed discription is given [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10116970/accessing-shared-folder-on-a-network-using-c-code.aspx)

EDIT:

And the link [Connect to a shared folder using IP address in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/184633/Connect-to-a-shared-folder-using-ip-address-in-vb6) can help you I think.

Comment: I am using DriveInfo.GetDrives() .In server its working fine when i access the site with IP adress in other machine it cannot find the mapped drives.